# Should questions about data science book recommendations be considered on-topic for Data Science?

Tags: discussion, flagging

One recent example:
[Can someone suggest good books or resources on SparkR?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116229/can-someone-suggest-good-books-or-resources-on-sparkr)

It seems to me that asking for book recommendations does not adhere to the [guidelines](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> Examples of questions that are on-topic for Data Science Stack Exchange:
>
> - Given process monitoring data arriving every 10ms, what statistical
>   tool should I use to best characterize a change in the process -
>   mean? a distribution?
> - I would like to produce a infographic on the 'Brexit' referendum. Given public opinion data across the UK, what are some meaningful
>   techniques to visualize it in a dashboard?
> - When executing an ARIMA model in Spark, what are the pros and cons of using Python instead of R?

But I see also that there were a few questions about rewarded in the past.

[Books on Reinforcement Learning](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6694/books-on-reinforcement-learning)?

[Can anyone recommend some good books or articles on working with time series?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37558/can-anyone-recommend-some-good-books-or-articles-on-working-with-time-series)?

So should a question such as the one linked at the top be flagged or just let go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are typically off-topic because what is or is not a "good" book is usually a matter of opinion. However, if the OP is somehow able to clearly define the parameters of the book search (e.g. the most cited book) the question could possibly have a best/correct answer and I would consider it to be on topic.

Comment: It's interesting that there is a book tag. I would not expect a tag for something that is generally off-topic.

Comment: Tags are created by users, and thus there is not necessarily governance around there creation.